# Marshal struct field to JSON without field name

Tags: go

I need to marshal into this JSON format:

```
{"messageProtocolHandshake":[{"handshakeType":"announceMax"},{"version":[{"major":1},{"minor":0}]}]}
```

Problem is matching the `handshakeType`. My struct is

```
type MessageProtocolHandshake struct {
    HandshakeType HandshakeType `json:"handshakeType"`
    Version       []Version     `json:"version"`
}

type HandshakeType struct {
    HandshakeType string
}
```

Marshaling can be done using slice of interface:

```
func (h MessageProtocolHandshake) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    res := make([]interface{}, 3)

    res[0] = struct {
        HandshakeType string `json:"handshakeType"`
    }{h.HandshakeType.HandshakeType}
    res[1] = struct {
        Version []Version `json:"version"`
    }{h.Version}

    return json.Marshal(res)
}
```

Using a simple marshaler/unmarshaler takes away the surrounding curly brackets from the `handshakeType`, so that doesn't work:

```
{"messageProtocolHandshake":[{"handshakeType":"announceMax","version":[{"major":1,"minor":0}],"formats":[{"format":"JSON-UTF8"}]}]}
```

Seems as if Go applies some heuristic in that case on the retuned byte array (undocumented?).

Is there a more elegant way of omitting the structs outer field name?

--

**UPDATE** To summarise the answers: key is to think about different structs for marshalling and unmarshalling if nothing else works, potentially a using a 3rd presentation for working internally with the data.
When custom (Un)Marshalers come into play remember that promoted fields inherit their methods and hence influence parent structs.

Comment: *"simple marshaler/unmarshaler takes away the surrounding curly brackets from the handshakeType"* -- No it doesn't, at least not in the way you've presented, `encoding/json` will not produce the "non working" json with *those* Go struct types. *"Seems as if Go applies some heuristic in that case on the retuned byte array (undocumented?)."* -- It's more likely you just misunderstood the documentation.

Comment: *"Is there a more elegant way of omitting the structs outer field name?"* -- By redesigning the struct types to better match the target json.

Comment: @mkopriva: did you try the code in deleted post by burak below? Imho it does as I wrote. If you have an explanation as to why that would help, too.

Comment: If by *"simple marshaler/unmarshaler"* you meant Burak's suggestion then yes, that would produce that json. Then, however, your *"Seems as if Go applies some heuristic in that case on the retuned byte array (undocumented?)."* statement makes even less sense. Can you be more specific about what the "undocumented heuristic" that you see applied to the output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON that you specified has a different model from that of your struct.

There are a few approaches to aligning these: Change the specification of the JSON data to match your structs, change the structs to match the specification of the JSON, or create a new struct that is only used for marshaling.

I omit the last example, because it's very similar to the second method.

---

### Changing the specification of the JSON

The following model stays the same:

```golang
type MessageProtocolHandshake struct {
    HandshakeType HandshakeType `json:"handshakeType"`
    Version       []Version     `json:"version"`
}

type HandshakeType struct {
    HandshakeType string
}
```

The JSON for this would be:

```json
{"handshakeType":{"HandshakeType":""},"version":[]}
```

You did not specify the `Version` type so I don't know how one would change the JSON for that.

---

### Changing the structs

The following JSON stays the same:

```json
{"messageProtocolHandshake":[{"handshakeType":"announceMax"},{"version":[{"major":1},{"minor":0}]}]}
```

The structs for this would be:

```golang
type Model struct {
    MessageProtocolHandshake []interface{} `json:"messageProtocolHandshake"`
}

type HandshakeType struct {
    HandshakeType string `json:"handshakeType"`
}

type Versions struct {
    Version []Version `json:"version"`
}

type Version struct {
    Major *int `json:"major,omitempty"`
    Minor *int `json:"minor,omitempty"`
}
```

Unmarshaling would not be trivial.

https://play.golang.org/p/89WUhcMFM0B

---

As is obvious from the results, the models you are using are not good. If there's a way to change all of this, I would recommend starting from scratch, using the data that is necessary and creating the JSON specification from the structs.

I recommend reading up on JSON: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Also, I recommend this introduction to Go and JSON: https://blog.golang.org/json